# extracting first element from a statement in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, extract

I have a column called people in my table which is a statement. I need to extract only the names from that column.

people:

```
Ramu is a good dancer.
Raj is the highest scorer in maths.
```

I need to extract only names (ramu,raj) from these statements. 
Hint: names before `is` since all statements has a word `is` here.

I don't how to extract in postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`split_part():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
with people(statement) as (
values
    ('Ramu is a good dancer.'),
    ('Raj is the highest scorer in maths.')
)

select split_part(statement, ' ', 1) as name
from people;

 name 
------
 Ramu
 Raj
(2 rows)
```